# Collection view cells flickers when populated dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have three collection views on a view,Heading collection-view,Outer collection-view and Inner collection-view...The custom cells are recipe-heading and innercell respectively. Inner collection-view is inside outercollectionview.

Outer collection view has 8 cells (depending on recipetypeArray) and inner cell has 25 cells(depending on recipe response array).When outercell1 moves to outercell2 ,the heading cell1 should also move to headingcell2 and so on.As the data in inner cell is dynamic ,so it should keep changing depending on the response received from server taking category id(current cell of outercollection view),page1 and limit 25(sat statically for the time being).

**Problem**
The images on cells(inner cell)keeps changing showing different images at a time causing flickering effect.Even the labels on cell also keep changing which is absolutely wrong.

**Code done is as follows:**
**RecipesViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
        [self callService:@0]; }

-(void)callService:(NSNumber*)categoryid{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];//for server hit
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];
    [manager POST:@"https://www.foodfuels.com/Api/getrecipes" parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        responseArray = nil;
        responseArray = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];
        responseDict = responseObject;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_outerCollectionView reloadData];
            [outerCell.innerCollectionView reloadData];
            [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }); }
    
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  *_Nullable task, NSError  *_Nonnull error) {
              [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
                           }]; }
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell
    forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(collectionView==_outerCollectionView){ dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self callService:rowValue];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_headingCollectionView reloadData];
            [_headingCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
        });
     });
    }
}
```

**RecipeInnerCell**

```
  -(void)populateRecipeScreen:(NSArray*)recipeResponseArr index:(NSIndexPath*)path{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"value of indexpath.row is %ld",path.row);
            
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if([[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:path.row]isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
    
                    self.titleLbl.text =[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:path.row];
                  }
                else{
                    self.titleLbl.text =@"";
    
                }
                if([[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"username"]  objectAtIndex:path.row]isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
    
                 self.subTitleLbl.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"username"]  objectAtIndex:path.row];
                }
                else{
                   self.subTitleLbl.text=@"";
                }
                //-----like_count---//
                if(![[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"like_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    
                self.like_Count.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"like_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
                }
                else{
                    self.like_Count.text=@"";
                }
                if(![[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comment_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    
                self.comment_Count.text =[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comment_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
                }else{
                    self.comment_Count.text=@"";
                }
                if(![[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"share_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    
                self.share_Count.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"share_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
                }
                else{
                    self.share_Count.text=@"";
                }
                if(![[[recipeResponseArr  valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"image"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    
                [self.smallImgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[[[recipeResponseArr  valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"image"]objectAtIndex:path.row]]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"]];
                }
                else{
                     self.smallImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"];
                }   
                
                if(![[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"upload_images"]objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"name"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    
                [self.mainImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"upload_images"]objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"name"]firstObject]]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"]];
                }
                else{
                  self.mainImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"];
                }
              
                if(![[[[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comments"]objectAtIndex:path.row]firstObject]valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"image"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    
                    [self.cmntImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comments"]objectAtIndex:path.row]firstObject]valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"image"]]
                                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"]];
                }
                else{
                    self.cmntImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-profile-128.png"];
                }
                
                //-----comment-----//
                if([[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comments"]objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"comment"]isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                    self.cmntSubtitle.text = [[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comments"]objectAtIndex:path.row]valueForKey:@"comment"]objectAtIndex:path.row];
                  }
                else{
                    self.cmntSubtitle.text =@"";
    
                    
                }
                
             
            });
        });
    }
```

**cellforrowatindexpath**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(collectionView==_headingCollectionView){
         recipeHeading = (RecipeHeadingCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
         _headingCollectionView.delegate = self;
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
        [recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitle:[recipeTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [recipeHeading.headingBtn layoutIfNeeded];
      
  
        [recipeHeading.headingBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     
       
        bool selected = [allValues[indexPath.row] boolValue];
        
        if(selected)
        {[recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            [recipeHeading.headingBtn addSubview:bottomBorder];
        }
        else
        {
        [recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    
        return recipeHeading;
    }
    else if (collectionView==_outerCollectionView){
        outerCell =(RecipeOuterCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"outerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        collectionView.pagingEnabled = true;
        
        return outerCell;
    }
    else{
        
        
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"innerCell";
        
        RecipeInnerCell *innerCell = (RecipeInnerCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // collectionView.pagingEnabled = true;
        [innerCell populateRecipeScreen:responseArray index:indexPath];
        return innerCell;
        
    }
}
```

**JSON Data**

```
<__NSArrayI 0x6040007a4520>(
{
    category = "<null>";
    "category_id" = "\"1\", \"3\", \"6\"";
    "comment_count" = 1;
    comments =     (
                {
            comment = "I had this for lunch so delicious.  I want it again for dinner";
            created = "2017-04-27T15:14:02-0500";
            "feed_id" = 0;
            id = 1726;
            modified = "2017-04-27T15:14:02-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1493324042;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Jill;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 3223;
                image = "https://www.foodfuels.com/media/user/3223.png";
                "last_name" = Gillette;
                username = Jillette;
            };
            "user_id" = 3223;
        }
    );
    created = "2016-03-22T01:48:28-0500";
    description = "Tuna, Egg, Avocado Salad";
    directions = "Mash together all of the ingredients and serve.";
    id = 38;
    ingredients = "\U2022 1 can tuna
\n\U2022 1 hard boiled egg
\n\U2022 \U00bd avocado sliced
\n\U2022 1 teaspoon freshly squeezed lime or lemon juice";
    "like_count" = 31;
    likes =     (
                {
            created = "2016-05-01T09:04:32-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 369;
            modified = "2016-05-01T09:04:32-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1462111472;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Kristine;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 1088;
                image = "https://graph.facebook.com/10209172098450544/picture?type=square";
                "last_name" = Demchuk;
                username = "Kristine Demchuk";
            };
            "user_id" = 1088;
        },
                {
            created = "2016-12-03T16:03:59-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 2446;
            modified = "2016-12-03T16:03:59-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1480799039;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Maureen;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2198;
                image = "2198.jpg";
                "last_name" = Miller;
                username = Mcm;
            };
            "user_id" = 2198;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-01-02T21:23:36-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 2648;
            modified = "2017-01-05T06:41:51-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 0;
            timestamp = 1483616511;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = charleyne;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2335;
                image = "2335.jpg";
                "last_name" = cawn;
                username = sherrislp;
            };
            "user_id" = 2335;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-01-07T23:24:28-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 2741;
            modified = "2017-01-07T23:24:28-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1483849468;
            user = "<null>";
            "user_id" = 2325;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-01-08T20:37:54-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 2755;
            modified = "2017-01-08T20:37:54-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1483925874;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Jillion;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2412;
                image = "2412.jpeg";
                "last_name" = Eskra;
                username = "Jillion Eskra";
            };
            "user_id" = 2412;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-02-05T08:57:23-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 2986;
            modified = "2017-02-05T08:57:23-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1486303043;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Melissa;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2559;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = "Gliottoni ";
                username = "";
            };
            "user_id" = 2559;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-03-04T17:54:07-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 3174;
            modified = "2017-03-04T17:54:13-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1488668053;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = HEATHER;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2676;
                image = "2676.jpg";
                "last_name" = KUNTZ;
                username = Hkntz83;
            };
            "user_id" = 2676;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-03-23T09:08:04-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 3510;
            modified = "2017-03-23T09:08:04-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1490278084;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Jamie;
                "group_id" = 2;
                id = 1978;
                image = "1978.jpg";
                "last_name" = Smith;
                username = Jamela321;
            };
            "user_id" = 1978;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-04-15T14:06:14-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 3781;
            modified = "2017-04-15T14:06:14-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1492283174;
            user = "<null>";
            "user_id" = 1589;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-07-09T23:46:37-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 4733;
            modified = "2017-07-09T23:46:37-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1499661997;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Asia;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 3870;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = Ferraro;
                username = ainegron;
            };
            "user_id" = 3870;
        },
             {
            created = "2017-08-11T07:27:02-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5002;
            modified = "2017-08-11T07:27:02-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1502454422;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Maria;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4050;
                image = "4050.jpg";
                "last_name" = Vuggica;
                username = mamamaria15;
            };
            "user_id" = 4050;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-08-11T14:58:00-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5005;
            modified = "2017-08-11T14:58:05-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 0;
            timestamp = 1502481485;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Marjorie;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4059;
                image = "4059.jpg";
                "last_name" = Justic;
                username = mags23;
            };
            "user_id" = 4059;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-08-12T08:57:03-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5026;
            modified = "2017-08-12T08:57:10-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1502546230;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Julie;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 2583;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = Barwegen;
                username = barwegenj;
            };
            "user_id" = 2583;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-08-13T07:48:23-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5027;
            modified = "2017-08-13T07:48:23-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1502628503;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Scott;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4138;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = Williams;
                username = Scott;
            };
            "user_id" = 4138;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-08-18T09:56:33-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5057;
            modified = "2017-08-18T09:56:43-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1503068203;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Kathy;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4190;
                image = "4190.jpg";
                "last_name" = Longtin;
                username = Klongtin;
            };
            "user_id" = 4190;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-08-25T20:07:07-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5093;
            modified = "2017-08-25T20:07:21-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1503709641;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Amy;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4193;
                image = "4193.jpg";
                "last_name" = Bettenhausen;
                username = Amy2675;
            };
            "user_id" = 4193;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-10-04T20:49:27-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5468;
            modified = "2017-10-04T20:49:27-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1507168167;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Tricia;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4663;
                image = "thumb_4663.jpg";
                "last_name" = Nagel;
                username = mstrishy;
            };
            "user_id" = 4663;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-10-26T19:41:09-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5674;
            modified = "2017-10-26T19:41:09-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1509064869;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Charlyn;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 3383;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = Nutter;
                username = nutterc;
            };
            "user_id" = 3383;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-11-03T15:55:20-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5749;
            modified = "2017-11-03T15:55:20-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1509742520;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = "Jessica ";
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4969;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = Turf;
                username = jbt2017;
            };
            "user_id" = 4969;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-11-07T18:35:39-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5788;
            modified = "2017-11-07T18:35:45-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 0;
            timestamp = 1510097745;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Tracy;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4985;
                image = "";
                "last_name" = McKenney;
                username = Treyzamay;
            };
            "user_id" = 4985;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-11-08T10:46:46-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5794;
            modified = "2017-11-08T10:46:46-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1510156006;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Kathryn;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4739;
                image = "4739.jpg";
                "last_name" = Northcott;
                username = "Fotografer ";
            };
            "user_id" = 4739;
        },
                {
            created = "2017-11-11T10:27:40-0500";
            "feed_id" = "<null>";
            id = 5808;
            modified = "2017-11-11T10:27:40-0500";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            "status_id" = 1;
            timestamp = 1510414060;
            user =             {
                "first_name" = Jeff;
                "group_id" = 3;
                id = 4357;
                image = "4357.jpg";
                "last_name" = Worsham;
                username = Jworsham;
            };
            "user_id" = 4357;
        }
    );
    modified = "2016-03-22T01:48:28-0500";
    notes = "";
    "preparation_time" = "5 minutes";
    rating = 0;
    "serving_size" = "Male 8oz., Female 4oz.";
    "share_count" = 14;
    "status_id" = 1;
    title = "Tuna, Egg, Avocado Salad";
    "upload_images" =     (
                {
            "feed_id" = 0;
            id = 41;
            name = "https://www.foodfuels.com/media/dish/01314127911-1458611308.jpg";
            "recipe_id" = 38;
            type = dish;
            "user_id" = 25;
        }
    );
    user =     {
        email = "aaron@foodfuelsweightloss.com";
        "first_name" = Aaron;
        id = 25;
        image = "https://www.foodfuels.com/media/user/25.png";
        "last_name" = Boniecki;
        username = "Aaron Boniecki";
    };
    "user_id" = 25;
}
)
```

What's wrong with my code?

The view:

[image: Image attached to describe the view exactly]

Comment: Can you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: @trungduc,question updated,Kindly check.